# Python: Loop only printing last value

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program to print the odd numbers up to a certain number mathematically works, however, I'm having trouble printing every odd number.

For some reason the program only prints the final odd number:

```
x=0
N=input('What is your number?')
N=float(N)
check=(N/2)
if (check).is_integer()==1:
    print('Your number is even')
    index=N-N/2-1
    while x<=index:
        x=2*index+1
        print(x)
        index=index+1
else:
    print('Your number is odd')
    index=(N-1)/2
    while x<=index:
        x=2*index+1
        print(x)
        index=index+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your counting of the odd numbers is very.. *odd*. I cannot make out what you were trying to do. Why not simply start `x` at `1` and increment by 2 each time until you get to `N`?

```
x = 1
while x <= N:
    print(x)
    x += 2
```

You don't need to use `float` values here; stick with `int` and use the `%` modulus (remainder) operator; this has the advantage you can then use a `range()` to produce all odd numbers up to `N`:

```
N = int(input('What is your number?'))
if N % 2 == 0:
    print('Your number is even')
else:
    print('Your number is odd')

for x in range(1, N + 1, 2):
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few suggestions I'd make.

**First**, you're using a float but unless you're going to be using floating point numbers (numbers with a decimal) I'd recommend you stick with integers.

**Second**, if you're trying to check whether a number is even or odd, you should check out the [modulo](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) (%) operator.

**Third**, always keep things simple. Don't repeat your code unless you need to.

Here is an example of a simpler version of your program.

```
user_input=input('What is your number?')
user_input=int(user_input)
if user_input % 2 == 0:
    print('Your number is even')
else:
    print('Your number is odd')
for index in range(1, user_input+1, 2):
    print(index)
```

Finally, be aware that your script will error if you put in garbage input, like "y7" - to fix this you should/can use exception handling.